# Complex equation gives unexpected roots

Tags: matrices, complex-numbers, solution-verification

The following question requires you to find the number of distinct matrices in S:

Let ω ≠ 1 be a complex cube root of unity and S be the set of all non singular matrices of the form \begin{bmatrix} 
1&a&b \\ 
\omega&1&c \\ 
\omega^2&\omega&1\
\end{bmatrix} where each of a, b, and c is either ω or ω2.

From solving the matrix, we get $ac\omega^2-(a+c)\omega+1\neq0$. Now, both $ac\neq1$ and $(a+c)\neq1$ have to be simultaneously true, so I substituted $a= \frac{1}{c}$ in the second inequality and solved it; logically, this should yield the values a and c shouldn't become.

But I got $\omega$ and $\omega^2$ as the solutions.

I know there are better ways you solve this, but where did I mess up here?

Comment: Note if $a=\omega^2$ then the first two columns are dependent, and if $c=\omega^2$ then the bottom two rows are dependent, so you need $a=c=\omega$. $b$ doesn't show up in the determinant, so it can be either of the two values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition for invertibility is that $\omega^2ac-(a+c)\omega+1\ne0$. I.e. $(1-\omega a)(1-\omega c)\ne 0$, i.e. $a\ne\omega^2\land c\ne\omega^2$.

Which means $2$ matrices.

Comment: Yeah, I know that's the right and easy way to solve it. But can you point out where my method went wrong?

Comment: For one thing you have a different equation. @HarryHolmes

Comment: @HarryHolmes Assuming a typo and that the intention was to write my inequation: while it would be convenient for you that $a+b\ne1\land ac\ne1$, it doesn't look necessary or sufficient (provided that it's a condition on four cases): if anything, $a+b\ne1\lor ac\ne1$ is necessary (but it isn't, in principle and in point of fact, sufficient). It's also unclear why you would substitute $a=\frac1c$ in the inequation. If $ac=1$ were necessary, then ok, but here you only claim to have $ac\ne1$ (and your claim is possibly unwarranted).

Comment: I thought that if both those inequations were actually equations, then the very first inequation $ac\omega^2 -(a+c)\omega+1\neq 0$ would be wrong; the LHS would end up becoming equal to zero. Since $a \neq \frac{1}{c}$ is required, I thought that by substituting it into the other inequality $a+ c \neq 1$, and solving it, I would get the values that *wouldn't be the solutions*(as only then would the matrix solution equation stay an inequation). But yeah, now I realise why it wouldn't be sufficient; other coefficients might make the matrix solution equation equal to 0.

Comment: @HarryHolmes Now that I think about it, there's also the fact that $\omega^2-\omega+1\ne0$ because the primitive cube roots of $1$ are roots of $x^2+x+1$: the roots of $x^2-x+1$ are the primitive sixth roots of $1$.